# Calling a function within a class

Tags: php, class, function, this

I am having trouble calling a specific function within a class. The call is made:

```
   case "Mod10":        
        if (!validateCreditCard($fields[$field_name]))
      $errors[] = $error_message;
    break;
```

and the class code is:

```
class CreditCardValidationSolution {

    var $CCVSNumber = '';
    var $CCVSNumberLeft = '';
    var $CCVSNumberRight = '';
    var $CCVSType = '';
    var $CCVSError = '';

function validateCreditCard($Number) {

        $this->CCVSNumber      = '';
        $this->CCVSNumberLeft  = '';
        $this->CCVSNumberRight = '';
        $this->CCVSType        = '';
        $this->CCVSError       = '';

        // Catch malformed input.

        if (empty($Number) || !is_string($Number)) {
            $this->CCVSError = $CCVSErrNumberString;
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Ensure number doesn't overrun.
        $Number = substr($Number, 0, 20);

        // Remove non-numeric characters.
        $this->CCVSNumber = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $Number);

        // Set up variables.
        $this->CCVSNumberLeft  = substr($this->CCVSNumber, 0, 4);
        $this->CCVSNumberRight = substr($this->CCVSNumber, -4);
        $NumberLength          = strlen($this->CCVSNumber);
        $DoChecksum            = 'Y';

        // Mod10 checksum process...
        if ($DoChecksum == 'Y') {

            $Checksum = 0;

            // Add even digits in even length strings or odd digits in odd length strings.
            for ($Location = 1 - ($NumberLength % 2); $Location < $NumberLength; $Location += 2) {
                $Checksum += substr($this->CCVSNumber, $Location, 1);
            }

            // Analyze odd digits in even length strings or even digits in odd length strings.
            for ($Location = ($NumberLength % 2); $Location < $NumberLength; $Location += 2) {
                $Digit = substr($this->CCVSNumber, $Location, 1) * 2;
                if ($Digit < 10) {
                    $Checksum += $Digit;
                } else {
                    $Checksum += $Digit - 9;
                }
            }

            // Checksums not divisible by 10 are bad.
            if ($Checksum % 10 != 0) {
                $this->CCVSError = $CCVSErrChecksum;
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        return TRUE;
}
}
```

When I run the application - I get the following message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined
>   function validateCreditCard() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\validation.php
>   on line 339

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the class containing the function within which you use the Switch-Case inherit the  CreditCardValidationSolution Class....??

My guess would be that you are trying to call the function outside the class without inheriting it.... Maybe you just missed it....

**Edit After Reading Comment :** 
   What you need here is "Inheritance"

Take a look at the following links.....

http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/php-objects-page-4.php

http://marakana.com/blog/examples/php-inheritance.html

Hope this helps....

Comment: i am not using switch-case at all within the class. I am in the following:

Function1() trying to call Function2() and Function2() lives in ClassA but Function1 does not


I have not inherited it at all - I am very new to this so honestly I dont even know what that means but I think you are right. I am trying to call a function which resides inside of a class from the outside

Answer (score 2):

```
class Foo {

    // How may I be called?
    function bar() {
    }

    function baz() {
        // Use $this-> to call methods within the same instance
        $this->bar();
    }

    function eek() {
        // Use self:: to call a function within the same class statically
        self::bar();
    }

}

// Use [class]:: to call a class function statically
Foo::bar();

// Use [object]-> to call methods of objects
$fooInstance = new Foo();
$fooInstance->bar();
```

Calling methods [statically](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) or as an instance method is not necessarily interchangeable, beware. That's all pretty well covered in the [basics of OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) by the way.

Comment: I saw this example elsewhere but not sure it applies to what I'm doing. Maybe it does and I'm misreading but I am basically trying to call a function and have it run through validations. Unfortunately, the function I found is laid inside of a class (and laden with $this variables) so I keep running into issues. 

I have another CASE and FUNCTION working in the exact same method with the exception there is no class and $this var

Comment: @JM4 If the function is part of a class, you'll need to call it as `[class]::` or `[object]->`, the functions are *not* part of the global namespace. Whether to call the function statically (`::`) or as instance method of an object (`->`) depends on the design of the function. Since it uses `$this`, it *needs* to be called as an instance method (`->`). So you'll have to create a new instance of the class (using `new`). There may be strings attached to instantiating the class, that should be documented or you'll have to read the code carefully.

Comment: @JM4 In more concrete code: `$ccVal = new CreditCardValidationSolution(); $ccVal->validateCreditCard();`